# How can i mock a typescript interface with jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I would like to mock a typescript interface, How can i achieve this?
I want to return 'Test' and ALIVE when i get the properties of human.
I'm having difficulty trying to compile the given code below.

### Error

```
TS2345: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Human'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Human'.
```

### Sample code

```
enum STATUS
{
   DEAD,
   ALIVE
}
    
export interface Human {
   name: string;
   status: STATUS.ALIVE | STATUS.DEAD;
};
  
describe('Human', () => {
   const mock = jest.fn<Human,[]>(() => {
    name   : jest.fn(() => { return 'Test' });
    status : jest.fn(() => { return STATUS.ALIVE });
});

it('should return properties',() => {
    console.log(human.name);
    console.log(human.status);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning mocked functions for `name` and `status` properties, but they are **NOT** function types. You should return `string` and `enum` for these two properties of `Human` interface.

```
enum STATUS {
  DEAD,
  ALIVE,
}

export interface Human {
  name: string;
  status: STATUS.ALIVE | STATUS.DEAD;
}

describe('Human', () => {
  const mock = jest.fn<Human, []>(() => {
    return {
      name: 'Test',
      status: STATUS.ALIVE,
    };
  });

  it('should return properties', () => {
    const human = mock();
    expect(human.name).toEqual('Test');
    expect(human.status).toEqual(STATUS.ALIVE);
  });
});
```